# Begin the column at the top of the title or at the top of the first main content text block?

Tags: website-design, layout, design-patterns, design, info-visualisation

On our homepage we have a content and a column with some boxes. What is the better approach:

**1. Begin the first column box at the top of the title:**

[image]

**2. Begin the first column box at the top of the first content text block**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with the term "Teaser"?

Comment: @Tony Bolero: I have converted the term 'Teaser' into column.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the relation between the title and the columns, I'd say. If your title also covers the second column, then the visual hierarchy should reflect that, i.e., you should follow (2). If the title is not related to the second column, approach (1) is right.

As an example, if the title says "Search Results for XYZ", and the second column contains general links to other pages of you site (not influenced by search), then follow (1).

Conversely, if your title says "News Items for Today", and both columns contain news items, follow (2).

Answer (score 1):

I am taking the liberty of assuming column text is something related / in context to the content on the page. This brings to mind many news websites and how they handle content.

Here are a couple of websites. [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/) and [NDTV](http://www.ndtv.com/) respectively.

[image: New York Times]

[image: NDTV]

1. They provide a clean header area for title. It gives central attention to the primary content on the page.
2. The upper area of column you talked about is kept for advertisements in many of the sites I have seen.
3. Just below the ads section there are inviting links with content on other pages of the site or somewhere on the web.

These are just few observations, but you are free to change it and give it a try. While doing so, you have to keep in mind user's mental model. If you keep content where many other sites keep ads, that content might be lost due to learned blindness or banner blindness.

However, some of the blog sites have a sidebar which have data at the column you mentioned. This approach is phasing out. Most of the new sites I am seeing like [Medium](https://medium.com/), [Subvtle](https://svbtle.com/) are doing away with sidebars.